# finalize() method in JAVA belongs to which class?

Tags: java

I would like to know the name of the class to which `finalize()` belong. To add a finalizer to a class, we will have to define the `finalize()` method. The JVM calls that that method whenever it is about to recycle an object of that class & should be `protected` always.

Answer (score 0):

finalize method belongs Object class.

Answer (score 0):

The (no-op) `finalize()` method is declared in `Object`.

However, if you want a finalizer to actually do something, you have to *override* `Object.finalize()` method in the class that needs finalization.

Hence the *real* `finalize()` method (i.e. the one than does something) belongs to the class that needs to be finalized.

---

Strictly speaking, your classes `finalize()` method does not have to be `protected`.  It *could* be `public`.  However, that would be a crazy thing to do, since it makes the `finalize()` method part of the public API, and invites unrelated code to call it.  That's something that you shouldn't need to happen.